# how to bind prop function to passing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, victory-charts

I am new with react and what I want here is, I want to access the `VictoryTooltip` context in `orientation` function, I can create a wrapper class of `VictoryTooltip` and can bind the context but that give some issue and I also want to know how we can bind function to passing component(this should be default befaviour). May be I am missing something very silly here. But I am bit stuck in this and need help. And yeah I tried also before putting a question here.

```
     { 
       // class body
       return ( <VictoryTooltip
        orientation={() => {
         console.log(this) //undefined 
        }}
        style={styles.tooltip}
        flyoutStyle={styles.tooltipContainer}
      />)
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `access the VictoryTooltip context`? Do you want to access the `VictoryTooltip` state from there? In an arrow function, the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used.

Comment: `VictoryTooltip` has some props(provided implicitly), that i want to use in `orientation` function to make orientation dynamic as per position. So if i can access `this`  of `VictoryTooltip` i would be able to get that. let me correct I am wrong here.

Comment: Since it doesn't look like `orientation` is called with `this` set to the `VictoryTooltip`, the only other way would be to add a `ref` to `VictoryTooltip` and refer to to the instance via that `ref`. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component However, `orientation` might be called before the component is rendered it which case that wouldn't work (in which case there is no way).

Comment: yeah, at firstplace I thourght of this but `ref` is also not given in api  list of `VictoryTooltip` https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-tooltip/

Comment: so you want to access the context of victorytooltip in the render of its parent via an inline lambda function? that just sounds like a bad architechture. Why dont you just pass a callback to the child that on didmount will call that callback with its context? aka https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrJbmg

Answer (score 0):

you can try like
`<VictoryTooltip   orientation="top" />`
or
`<VictoryTooltip orientation={this.myFunction.bind(this)}`
and write you `myFunction` inside the component class
Refer here for more https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-tooltip/#orientation

Comment: `orientation="top"` i knew that, dynamic orientation i am trying to implement, `<VictoryTooltip orientation={this.myFunction.bind(this)}` this will bind the function to container class not to `<VictoryTooltip>`